# Chi-Square Test of Independence

Tags: r, chi-squared

I am working with data from school districts and I am trying to use a chi-square test of independence in order to see whether they are predicative. My data looks like this:

```
school.district<-c(2543, 4354, 7687, 4210, 610, 241, 833)
enrolled.students<-c(1331, 1809, 2286, 1586, 225, 137, 394)
freq.enrolled<-c(0.171344, 0.2328785, 0.2942842, 0.204171, 0.02896498, 0.01763646, 0.05072091)

chisq.test(x=school.district, p=freq.enrolled)
```

When I run this code, however, I get the result:

```
Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  usbe.chi and usbe.enr.p
X-squared = 42, df = 36, p-value = 0.227

Warning message:
In chisq.test(x = usbe.chi, y = usbe.enr.p) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Am I doing the test correctly? Or do I need to change the 'y' in the chisq.test?

Comment: When you say you want see if if "they are predicative", what exactly is "they"? What is the hypothesis you are testing? What do these numbers represent? If you have statistical questions, those should be asked at [stats.se]. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions.

Comment: When I run your code, I get the error "error in chisq.test(x = school.district, p = freq.enrolled) : probabilities must sum to 1." Your null hypothesis is that the frequencies in `school.district` are not significantly different those expected based the proportions in `freq.enrolled` (`enrolled.students / sum(enrolled.students)`). The p-value of .227 indicates that you can "accept" (fail to reject) the null hypothesis. The warning indicates that there are probably very small probabilities which would inflate the chi square value.